# My symmetric encryption adds data to my rsa key I want to save and load encrypted

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

Currently I am trying to implement a save function for my RSA key with the help of bouncycastle. I am running into problems if I try to save my public or private key encrypted and load it afterwards.

As a little example here the original public key:

`305C300D06092A864886F70D0101010500034B00304802410096B4751049165D1E046063EA22E8FFA0F90AE1DD997A3876DA5F79C7DE97951F009AC9ACA3EB91114F8A32C04F48293B6665CD6DD5C406C81CD13270A2AB61130203010001`

What I get after loading it (it adds 4 zeroes, bigger key means more zeroes added):

`305C300D06092A864886F70D0101010500034B00304802410096B4751049165D1E046063EA22E8FFA0F90AE1DD997A3876DA5F79C7DE97951F009AC9ACA3EB91114F8A32C04F48293B6665CD6DD5C406C81CD13270A2AB611302030100010000`

I found out it has something to do with my implementation of the symmetric encryption and the padding used there. Normal text no matter how long it is just works fine without extra data getting added.

This is the code I am using for my AES encryption:

Encryption

```
byte[] outputBytes = new byte[0];
AesEngine aesengine = new AesEngine();
CbcBlockCipher aesblockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(aesengine);
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aescipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(aesblockCipher);
KeyParameter aeskeyParameter = new KeyParameter(Hash.HashDataBlock(password, Hash.HashAlgorithm.SHA3).Bytes);
aescipher.Init(true, aeskeyParameter);
outputBytes = new byte[aescipher.GetOutputSize(inputBytes.Bytes.Length)];
int aeslength = aescipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes.Bytes, outputBytes, 0);
aescipher.DoFinal(outputBytes, aeslength);
```

Decryption

```
byte[] inputBytes = input.Bytes;
byte[] outputBytes = new byte[0];
AesEngine aesengine = new AesEngine();
CbcBlockCipher aesblockCipher = new CbcBlockCipher(aesengine);
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aescipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(aesblockCipher);
KeyParameter aeskeyParameter = new KeyParameter(Hash.HashDataBlock(password, Hash.HashAlgorithm.SHA3).Bytes);
aescipher.Init(false, aeskeyParameter);
outputBytes = new byte[aescipher.GetOutputSize(inputBytes.Length)];
int aeslength = aescipher.ProcessBytes(inputBytes, outputBytes, 0);
aescipher.DoFinal(outputBytes, aeslength);
```

My Functions to save and load the keys. The DataBlock class just converts data to needed formats like UTF8, Base64 or just byte arrays:

```
public static void SaveKeyEncrypted(DataBlock key, string path, DataBlock password)
{
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
  DataBlock encrypted = SymmetricEncryption.Encrypt(key, password, SymmetricEncryption.SymmetricAlgorithms.AES);
  sw.Write(encrypted.Base64);
  sw.Close();
}

public static DataBlock ReadKeyEncrypted(string path, DataBlock password)
{
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
  DataBlock readData = new DataBlock(sr.ReadLine(), DataBlock.DataType.Base64);
  sr.Close();
  return SymmetricEncryption.Decrypt(readData, password, SymmetricEncryption.SymmetricAlgorithms.AES);
}
```

For reproduction my other code that has to do with this problem:

```
public class DataBlock
    {
        private byte[] _data;

        public DataBlock()
        {
            this._data = new byte[0];
        }

        public enum DataType
        {
            UTF8,
            UTF7,
            UTF32,
            ASCII,
            Unicode,
            Hex,
            Base64,
            Base32
        }

        public DataBlock(string data, DataType dataType) : this()
        {
            switch (dataType)
            {
                case DataType.UTF8:
                    this._data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                    break;
                case DataType.UTF7:
                    this._data = Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(data);  
                    break;
                case DataType.UTF32:
                    this._data = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(data);
                    break;
                case DataType.ASCII:
                    this._data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                    break;
                case DataType.Unicode:
                    this._data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);
                    break;
                case DataType.Hex:
                    this._data = new byte[data.Length / 2];
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2)
                    {
                        this._data[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(i, 2), 16);
                    }
                    break;
                case DataType.Base64:
                    this._data = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
                    break;
                case DataType.Base32:
                    this._data = this.FromBase32String(data);
                    break;
            }
        }

        public DataBlock(byte[] data)
        {
            this._data = data;
        }

        public string UTF8
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(this._data);
            }
        }

        public string UTF7
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.UTF7.GetString(this._data);
            }
        }

        public string UTF32
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.UTF32.GetString(this._data);
            }
        }

        public string ASCII
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._data);
            }
        }

        public string Unicode
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(this._data);
            }
        }

        public string Hex
        {
            get
            {
                return BitConverter.ToString(this._data).Replace("-", "");
            }
        }

        public string Base64
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToBase64String(this._data);
            }
        }

        public string Base32
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ToBase32String(this._data);
            }
        }

        public byte[] Bytes
        {
            get
            {
                return this._data;
            }
        }

        private string ValidChars = "QAZ2WSX3" + "EDC4RFV5" + "TGB6YHN7" + "UJM8K9LP";

        private string ToBase32String(byte[] bytes)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte index;
            int hi = 5;
            int currentByte = 0;

            while (currentByte < bytes.Length)
            {
                if (hi > 8)
                {
                    index = (byte)(bytes[currentByte++] >> (hi - 5));
                    if (currentByte != bytes.Length)
                    {
                        index = (byte)(((byte)(bytes[currentByte] << (16 - hi)) >> 3) | index);
                    }

                    hi -= 3;
                }
                else if (hi == 8)
                {
                    index = (byte)(bytes[currentByte++] >> 3);
                    hi -= 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    index = (byte)((byte)(bytes[currentByte] << (8 - hi)) >> 3);
                    hi += 5;
                }

                sb.Append(ValidChars[index]);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public byte[] FromBase32String(string str)
        {
            int numBytes = str.Length * 5 / 8;
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[numBytes];
            str = str.ToUpper();

            int bit_buffer;
            int currentCharIndex;
            int bits_in_buffer;

            if (str.Length < 3)
            {
                bytes[0] = (byte)(ValidChars.IndexOf(str[0]) | ValidChars.IndexOf(str[1]) << 5);
                return bytes;
            }

            bit_buffer = (ValidChars.IndexOf(str[0]) | ValidChars.IndexOf(str[1]) << 5);
            bits_in_buffer = 10;
            currentCharIndex = 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] = (byte)bit_buffer;
                bit_buffer >>= 8;
                bits_in_buffer -= 8;
                while (bits_in_buffer < 8 && currentCharIndex < str.Length)
                {
                    bit_buffer |= ValidChars.IndexOf(str[currentCharIndex++]) << bits_in_buffer;
                    bits_in_buffer += 5;
                }
            }

            return bytes;
        }
    }
```

Function to generate a keypair

```
public static DataBlock[] GenerateKeyPair(KeyPairSize keyPairSize)
        {
            RsaKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
            keyPairGenerator.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), (int) keyPairSize));
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
            PrivateKeyInfo pkInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(keyPair.Private);
            SubjectPublicKeyInfo info = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keyPair.Public);
            DataBlock[] keyPairData = new DataBlock[2];
            keyPairData[0] = new DataBlock(pkInfo.GetDerEncoded());
            keyPairData[1] = new DataBlock(info.GetDerEncoded());
            return keyPairData;
        }
```

Code to reproduce the error:

```
DataBlock[] keyPair = AsymmetricEncryption.GenerateKeyPair(AsymmetricEncryption.KeyPairSize.Bits512);
DataBlock pass = new DataBlock("1234", DataBlock.DataType.UTF8);
DataBlock orig = new DataBlock("Hello World", DataBlock.DataType.UTF8);
DataBlock encrypted = AsymmetricEncryption.Encrypt(orig, keyPair[1]);
AsymmetricEncryption.SaveKeyEncrypted(keyPair[0], "D:\\privateenc", pass);
AsymmetricEncryption.SaveKeyEncrypted(keyPair[1], "D:\\publicenc", pass);
DataBlock privateKey = AsymmetricEncryption.ReadKeyEncrypted("D:\\privateenc", pass);
DataBlock publicKey = AsymmetricEncryption.ReadKeyEncrypted("D:\\publicenc", pass);
DataBlock decrypted = AsymmetricEncryption.Decrypt(encrypted, privateKey);
Console.WriteLine(decrypted.UTF8);
```

The encryption/decryption method is not needed because the error already happens after reading the encrypted key on my harddrive.

Why/where is the extra data added and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's better to have some reproducible example here. I can't reproduce it without `DataBlock` source code. Can you make the code example reproducible? If possible.

Comment: Tip: You may simplify key read/write as `DataBlock readData = new DataBlock(File.ReadAllText(path), DataBlock.DataType.Base64);` without `sr`. Same for `.WriteAllText`.

Comment: I updated my question for easier reproduction

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding the initial byte array length of the key to the encrypted text and read it later on. In the read function I cut everything after the original size of the key.

The main problem is still present and this is just a workaround.